# How to change the colour of an SVG when at the start/end of slick slider

Tags: php, html, wordpress, slick.js

Sorry if the title sucks, I didn't really know how to word it...

How would I change the colour of the svg arrows if I'm at the start of the slides or at the end of the slides? Maybe I could add class if value equals 0? not sure how to approach adding a class if there are no slides remaining?

The Image below is what I'm trying to achieve.. atm I have two white arrows on both sides. I want to change the colour to that grey when at the start (on the left) and if I'm at the end (on the right).

```
    $(".image_carousel-wrapper").each(function () {
        var _this = $(this);

        var $status = _this.find('.slide-number');
        var $slickElement = _this.find('.image_carousel');

        $slickElement.on('init reInit afterChange', function (event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide) {
            //currentSlide is undefined on init -- set it to 0 in this case (currentSlide is 0 based)
            if (!slick.$dots) {
                return;
            }

            var i = (currentSlide ? currentSlide : 0) + 1;
            $status.text(i + '/' + (slick.$dots[0].children.length));
        });



        var _this = $(this);
        _this.find('.image_carousel').slick({
            arrows: true,
            dots: true,
            pauseOnHover: false,
            pauseOnFocus: false,
            autoplay: false,
            swipeToSlide: true,
            fade: true,
            draggable: true,

            prevArrow: _this.find('.prev-slide'),
            nextArrow: _this.find('.next-slide'),
        });
    });
```

```
            <div class="image_carousel-wrapper">
                <div class="image_carousel">
                    <?php foreach( $images as $image ): ?>
                        <div class="slide">
                        
                            <img class="full-width <?php if($module_alignment == 'left') : ?>left-image<?php endif; ?>" src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>">


                            <?php if( get_sub_field('artists_impression') ): ?> 
                                <p class="artistimp ">Artist Impression</p>
                            <?php endif; ?>


                        </div>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>

                    
                </div>

                <div class="slider-directions">
                    <div class="arrow-wrap">
                        <div class="prev-slide"></div>
                        <div class="next-slide"></div>
                    </div>
                <div class="slide-number"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `infinite: false` to the carousel options to disable infinite looping.

If you want to further tweak the look of the disabled nav item, you can target `.slick-disabled`